# How to block domains with python

Tags: python, web, dns, firewall, network-security

does anyone know how to block a domain with python? It doesn't really matter what package it is but standard library is better. So what I think when I say blocking domains is when I type in my python program facebook.com. It will block any request any kind of thing related to the website, it will be blocked. I was thinking about typing a script that will check for the IP address of the domain and type it into the iptables on my Ubuntu Linux. But then I was told that Facebook and other big companies switch/change domain IP addresses often. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Why use python? why not use a built-in function in Linux?

Comment: My task/job is to do this in python :/

Comment: You can always check the shell commands required, and then type them in python as:

```import os
os.system("your shell code here")
```
Thats a workaround but not a "real" solution (Macros are bad practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block any domain in DNS using your Firewall, or by editing 'hosts' file and pointing all requests to 0.0.0.0

Comment: what i mean is that when i type in the program it will block that domain on my computer. So if i type google.com, it will block all requests for that domain. And only for my computer, so no dns server here.

Comment: You computer always uses local DNS before going to web. 
Usually it looks for domain IP in 'hosts' file (%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts for Windows and /etc/hosts for Unix system), then, if no record found, request IP from your ISP DNS.
You can write 'example com    0.0.0.0' in your 'hosts' file to make 'example.com' unaccessible from your machine.